# Gravar um valor Dword, Decimal em 64 Bits

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim Numero = 22i
    My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MinhaChaveCriada",
   "DECIMAL 64 Bits", Numero, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
End Sub
```

Quando eu uso  Dim Numero = 22i o `i` da integer representa um valor para 32 bits como gravo em 64 bits? Já tirei o `i` e ele continua a gravar em 32 bits.
Já resolvi podem excluir.

Comment: Desculpem o Valor é Qword 64 bits

Comment: Por favor use o link de [edit] para corrigir o título e o código com qword então.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ficou assim no final .
 Dim Numero = 22
        My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MinhaChaveCriada",
       "DECIMAL 64 Bits Qword", Numero, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.QWord)

Ja pedi pra removerem o post , ninguém removeu ainda... .